# Adding Text on includepdf - margin/baseline problem!

Tags: pdfpages, baseline

If i put a short text it works fine.

```
\put(200,300){short text}%
```

If i put a long text it goes out of boundary.

```
\put(200,200){long long long long long long long long long long long long text}% goes out of boundary
```

**Problem with adding box around Text:**

The Text has to start exactly at e.g. (200,300). So if i put addmargin, tcolorbox etc. around the text, it starts at the next line and not (200,300).

```
\documentclass[a4,11pt,twoside,german]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}


\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=1,%
     picturecommand*={%
     \put(200,300){short text}% works fine
     \put(200,200){long long long long long long long long long long long long text}% goes out of boundary
}]{example.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Anyone suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\put` a `\parbox[t]` to confine the width and to start at the proper location.

In the MWE I place an `X` also to mark the spot and you will see the parbox starts at that same location.

EDITED to adapt to colorbox.  Since it is not clear if the box or the text needs to start at that point, I provide both alternatives in the MWE.  In one case, you have to lower the box by `\fboxrule+\fboxsep` and in the other case, you have to kern the box leftward by `\fboxrule+\fboxsep`.

```
\documentclass[a4,11pt,twoside,german]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=1,%
     picturecommand*={%
     \put(200,300){short text}% works fine
     \put(200,200){\raisebox{-9pt}{\fboxrule=3pt\fboxsep=6pt\relax
  \fcolorbox{red}{blue!40}{\parbox[t]{1in}{\textcolor{white}{long 
  long long long long long long long long long long long 
  text}}}}}% goes out of boundary
     \put(200,200){X}% works fine
%
     \put(320,200){\kern-9pt\fboxrule=3pt\fboxsep=6pt\relax
  \fcolorbox{red}{blue!40}{\parbox[t]{1in}{\textcolor{white}{long 
  long long long long long long long long long long long 
  text}}}}% goes out of boundary
     \put(320,200){X}% works fine
}]{example-image.pdf}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! Is it possible to get this with tcolorbox? If i use tcolorbox, the text starts at the next line...

Comment: @BilalYilmaz I am not a `tcolorbox` expert, sadly.  If you don't mind square corners, you could wrap a `\colorbox` around the `\parbox`.

Comment: Ok i will try. And thanks for the solution with parbox! I am not so used with these box types, therefore my strategy was to get it done with tcolorbox. But maybe i mix things up. Thank again!

Comment: @BilalYilmaz Please see my edited answer.

Comment: you used raisbox with -9pt. How can we measure the height of the text? Then we could make "- \somecomand pt" instead of -9t.

Comment: @BilalYilmaz I did not need to calculate the height of the text, since the `[t]` option of `\parbox` did that.  The 9pt I used was purely due to the border size of the box, being the sum of the blue border (`\fboxsep`) plus the red border (`\fboxrule`).  If neither of the two boxes provided is what you need, you would have to be more specific about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @BilalYilmaz If you wanted a consistency that did not depend on whether the top line of the box was all short letters like `a` or contained tall letters like `X`, you could start out each box text with `\strut`, which adds an invisible character that has no width but the vertical height of one line of text.

Comment: setting boxrule and boxsep both = 0pt makes the same problem. It makes a linebreak so thath "long long..." is not at X(320,200). Can u compile and check this?

Comment: i used:
\begin{tcolorbox}[box align=top,enhanced,interior hidden,colframe=red!10!,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,boxrule=0mm,arc=0mm,boxsep=0mm,opacityfill=1]{ \parbox[t]{1in}{\textcolor{white}{long 
  long long long long long long long long long long long 
  text}}}